# Error al publicar proyecto de análisis services en IIS7

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis

Tengo un problema, en una solución de Visual Studio 2013 tengo 2 proyectos, uno que es la parte gráfica y manejo de lógica del proyecto y otro que es un proyecto de Business Intelligence donde manejo cubos, como mencioné ambos proyectos están dentro de una misma solución. El problema que tengo es que publico la solución, entro al sitio web, pero al querer procesar el cubo desde el proyecto publicado da error, sin embargo, si lo corro localmente todo va bien. Alguna idea de cual puede ser el error?

El mensaje de error es:

```
"No se puede establecer conexión con el servidor"
```

Comment: cual es el mensaje de error que le genera?

Comment: no establece conexion con el servidor. Sin embargo, si lo corro sin publicarlo, funciona sin problemas. Ahora estoy intentando publicar el projecto por aparte en el IIS7, y luego al projecto de Business Intelligence le doy deploy por aparte, sin embargo, tampoco resulta.

Comment: Es probable que el servidor Web esta en la DMZ y esta no alcanza al servidor de Base de Datos.